# Por qué me imprime doble el printf en C

Tags: c

tengo un problema que no logro solucionar ni encontrar el error.

```c
void carga(char a[], int b){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<b;i++){
        printf("Ingrese caracter\n");
        scanf("%c", &a[i]);
    }
}
```

Cuestión que cuando, pongo a ejecutar, en esta parte del programa (una función) el cartel se imprime

```
Ingrese caracter
Ingrese caracter
_
```

Comment: a mi solo me aparece 1 vez :/

Answer (score 1):

Lo que está pasando es que tu `scanf` está agarrando algún caracter de newline (`'\n'`) de tu buffer de salida, entonces cree que ya ingresaste un número. Para arreglar esto puedes agregar un espacio antes del `%c` de tu `scanf`, así:

```
scanf(" %c", &a[i]);
```

Al usar ese espacio le indicamos a `scanf` que descarte cualquier espacio en blanco, esto incluye los `newline` anteriores que probablemente dejas en el buffer al hacer enter en las opciones anteriores o tal vez producto de tus `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no hay un error en tu lógica. Por como lo estructuraste es normal que se imprima varias veces, ya que cada que se ejecute el ciclo for (dependiendo del valor de b) el mensaje aparecerá y podrás ingresar un nuevo número en la siguiente posición de tu arreglo:

```c
for(i=0;i<b;i++){
    printf("Ingrese caracter\n");
    scanf("%c", &a[i]);
}
```

Podrías optimizarlo de la siguiente manera para que veas que número es el que esta guardando en dicha posición, y que si coincida con lo que ingresaste:

```c
for(i=0;i<b;i++){
    printf("Ingrese caracter\n");
    scanf("%c", &a[i]);
    printf("El caracter leído es: %c\n", a[i]);
}
```